# create "deadman switch" to lock computer

Tags: autohotkey

I use autohotkey to automate reports from various sources in a corporate environment. Security has become an issue as typically my computer runs scheduled scripts from my cube in the middle of the night. Can you suggest a way to create a "deadman switch" so that if someone touches my computer, it automatically locks it?
I have found this script which activates on using the F10 key.

```
^F10::

{

Sleep, 200

DllCall("LockWorkStation")

Sleep, 200

SendMessage,0x112,0xF170,2,,Program Manager

}

return
```

Any other suggestions are also welcomed.

Comment: Why not lock it in the first place?

Comment: What operating system is your computer running? Most operating systems allow you to lock the workstation whilst tasks are running in the background. I can't help but think you're trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Windows 7. Looking for a trigger that will lock the desktop if someone tries to access it. autohotkey runs reports when i am not around. If someone turns on the monitor, they can access everything on my computer...thanks for helping me clarify.

Comment: BTW...autohotkey at least the way i use it, needs access to the screens to navigate. Monitor can be off but the scripts will not run if the computer is locked.

Comment: Loop examining A_TimeIdlePhysical, if an input event occurs then LockWorkStation

Comment: How would the script know the difference between you accessing your own PC and you using it yourself? How would you regain access to your PC?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
Pause::Run, % "rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation"
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what commands you are using in your script.
If you are for example emulating clicks or reading pixelcolors form the screen, then you'd have to go with something like [BlockInput, On](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/BlockInput.htm). But prepare a mechanism to disable BlockInput again! For example you could check every 10 seconds if a specific key is held down.
If you are just parsing some textfiles in the background, playing a musicfile, creating a GUI etc, then the script does even work when the computer is locked. To lock the computer use this API call: [DllCall("LockWorkStation")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)